# Accessing malloc'd 2-D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function read_mat() that needs to read from a file and put values into a 2-d array that is passed by reference as an argument. After correctly allocating memory for it using malloc(), I have trouble putting in values to the array in the second to last positions. Its of size N x M, where N is rows and M is columns.

I seg-fault after trying to access a[0][3], which I would think should be the last column of the first row but apparently it doesn't exist in memory?? Using stdio.h, stdlib.h and my "header.h" file.

Edit: n = 3, m = 4

```
int read_mat(int *n, int *m, double ***a) {

//open file
FILE *fp = fopen("matrix.dat", "r");    
if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File open failed!\n");
    return -1;
}

//scan first line for size
fscanf(fp, "%d %d", n, m);

//TESTING
printf("Size of n(rows): %d\n", *n);
printf("Size of m(columns); %d\n", *m);

//malloc 1-d array of n # pointers
*a = malloc(*n * sizeof(double*));

//malloc space for m # of columns per row
for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    (*a)[i] = malloc(*m * sizeof(double));
}

//TESTING
fprintf(stderr, "passed malloc!\n");

//scan values and fill array
//rows loop
for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
    printf("value of i: %d\n", i);
    //column loop
    for (int j = 0; j < *m; j++) {
        printf("value of j: %d\n", j);
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", a[i][j]);
        printf("accessed a[%d][%d]!\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: "access a[0][3]" what is the values for `n` and `m` then?

Comment: Why don't you check return of `malloc` and `fscanf`'s ? How do you know calls to `malloc` were successfull ?

Comment: It wasn't an issue with malloc but with how I was calling the array locations, and I didn't know fscanf had a return value for number of elements assigned. I'll have to use that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
fscanf(fp, "%lf", a[i][j]);
```

is wrong. This accesses `i`th element of `a` and may be invalid when `i>0`.
What you want should be

```
fscanf(fp, "%lf", &(*a)[i][j]);
```

Adding some code to check if `fscanf()` is successful will make your code better.

Comment: That got me past the part on filling the array! Thanks a lot MikeCAT.